# Reduce Size of Cordova App

Tags: cordova

I'm building a Cordova app and My Html files in www folder are 450kb in size. I'm using AdMob plugin only. And My App Size Reach to 1.9MB. I want to Reduce my App Size to less than 1.5MB. I've done many things to reduce my app size such as:
1.Add cordova-uglify plugin
2.Remove Splashscreen
3.Minify my html,css,js and use svg instead of png
but my app size still 1.8MB
How can I reduce My App Size further? I think its all due to google play service and admob

Comment: You can delete all the images located in the platforms\android\res directory if you don't need a splash image to be shown

Comment: @NullPointer I already Did but still my apk 1.7mb in size